# Application.Resources in WPF from Template Copy - How can I get order into it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

Im pretty new to WPF. I needed to change the button mouseover colors so I right clicked the button, then copied the template. So Visual Studio got a lot of new lines into my `App.xaml` where I can now set the design of my button, looking like this:

```
<Application x:Class="Thermologger.Start.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Thermologger.Start"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
    <!--StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"-->
             
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#ff609d9f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#ff609d9f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Foreground" Color="white"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#cf609d9f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#cf609d9f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#cf609d9f"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="black"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
```

And a lot more!

So now I want to do that with another button and other colors - so I did the same again, that is when visual studio starts to number it like:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#ff609d9f"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background1" Color="#ff609d9f"/>
```

And because it is a lot of auto generated lines, my `App.xaml` is about 500+ lines long for just a few color changes in buttons.

So my question is, how can I do better now?

It would help me to be able to extract each button into it's own files to get a bit cleaner files like `SaveButton.xaml` or `CancelButton.xaml` and reimport them when I need them.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new resource dictionary *Project* > *Add new item...* > *Resource Dictionary (WPF)* and name it `SaveButton.xaml`. Copy the resources over to this new resource dictionary.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
               <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
   <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#ff609d9f"/>

   <!-- ...other resources. -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Create a dictionary for the other button styles as well and add them to the application resources.

```
<Application x:Class="Thermologger.Start.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Thermologger.Start"
             Startup="Application_Startup">
   <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="SaveButton.xaml"/>
            <!-- ...other resource dictionaries. -->
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If you only want to change the colors, you do not need to duplicate the button styles and templates. One approach could be to separate the brushes for your distinct styles like the following:

- Create a resource dictinary, e.g. `ButtonStyles.xaml`.
- Extract the default button styles and templates there.
- Rename the button style `x:Key` to `BaseButtonStyle`.
- Replace all `StaticResource` and `x:Static` references that target brushes with the [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) markup extension (resolves resources at runtime - here brushes)
- Create a style for one of your buttons that is based on your neutral base style `BaseButtonStyle` and **move all of the brushes** from the base style to the `Resources` of the new style.
- Customize the brushes to get your custom style.
- Copy this style with the brushes for each new button, replace its `x:Key` and adapt the brushes.

Add the resource dictionary to the application resources just like above. Now, you can reference each special button style in your code explicitly using its `x:Key`.

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button Style="{DynamicResource SaveButtonStyle}" Content="Test"/>
   <Button Style="{DynamicResource CancelButtonStyle}" Content="Test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[At runtime the brushes will be resolved searching up the logical tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0#dynamic-resource-lookup-behavior). Since the brushes are not available in the base style, they are found in your derived style in the lookup process.  For more information about resource lookup, refer to [Overview of XAML resources (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0).

> The lookup checks for the requested key within the resource dictionary defined by the element that sets the property [...]
> The lookup traverses the logical tree upward to the parent element and its resource dictionary. This process continues until the root element is reached. [...]

Here is an example of such a resource dictionary for your *Save* and *Cancel* buttons with lazy coloring.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
   <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
               <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
   <Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FocusVisual}"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
               <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                  <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
               </Border>
               <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                     <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                  </Trigger>
                  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                     <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                     <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                  </Trigger>
               </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
      <Style.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="Red"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="Blue"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="Yellow"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="Purple"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="Green"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="Orange"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="Brown"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="Aqua"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="AntiqueWhite"/>
      </Style.Resources>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="CancelButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}">
      <Style.Resources>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="Black"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="DarkSlateGray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="DimGray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="DarkGray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="LightGray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="Gray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="GhostWhite"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="DimGray"/>
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="LightSlateGray"/>
      </Style.Resources>
   </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Of course, you could also split them into several distinct resource dictionaries if you want.

Comment: That is a hell of a quality answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like the following in your custom button style or create a general style targeted to a Button and then use it in the Buttons that you want.

```html
          <Style.Triggers>                                       
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"   Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>
```

Alternatively, you could use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events and change the color in code behind manually, but this is usually not prefered